# How to style first acronym and first glossary appearance

Tags: formatting, glossaries, acronyms

I would like to define the following styling for my acronyms and glossary in my latex project.

---

[image]

### or look [here](https://de.overleaf.com/read/bxhfrrkzddsg) for a small example in Overleaf

Currently I have tried it with the following code but the result was 
 that all following occurends will have the superscript "gl".

`\usepackage[acronym , toc]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}
\newcommand*{\glossfirstformat}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{#1\textsuperscript{gl}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE). That said, you explicitly request the superscript at `\textsuperscript{gl}`.

Comment: Hi Texnician i have add a  minimal compilable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to use the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\firstuseformat}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\glslinkpresetkeys}{% requires v1.26+
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
  {\letcs\glstextformat{@firstofone}}%
  {\let\glstextformat\firstuseformat}%
}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkabbreviation}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{ab}}}
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkgeneral}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{gl}}}

\newabbreviation{HW}{HW}{Hello World}

\newglossaryentry{entropie}{name={entropie},
 description={...}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{HW} and \gls{entropie}.

Next use: \gls{HW} and \gls{entropie}. 

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

If your version of `glossaries-extra` is too old, `\glslinkpresetkeys` won't be defined, but you can use `\glslinkpostsetkeys` instead (which is provided by the base `glossaries` package as from v4.16).

If you prefer to continue using `\newacronym` instead of `\newabbreviation` then you need to make a few modifications:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\firstuseformat}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\glslinkpresetkeys}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
  {\letcs\glstextformat{@firstofone}}%
  {\let\glstextformat\firstuseformat}%
}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkacronym}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{ab}}}
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkgeneral}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{gl}}}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{HW}{HW}{Hello World}

\newglossaryentry{entropie}{name={entropie},
 description={...}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{HW} and \gls{entropie}.

Next use: \gls{HW} and \gls{entropie}. 

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The result is very similar but the list of abbreviations has a different title:

[image: image of document]

Regarding the post-link hook commands, which are in the form `\glsxtrpostlink`*category*, as from version 1.31 you can (re)define them with `\glsdefpostlink{`*category*`}{`*definition*`}`. So if you have at least v1.31, you can replace:

```
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkabbreviation}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{ab}}}
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkgeneral}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{gl}}}
```

with

```
\glsdefpostlink{abbreviation}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{ab}}}
\glsdefpostlink{general}{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{gl}}}
```

Another variation is to use `\glsxtrdopostpunc` within the post-link hook to check for certain punctuation marks. For example:

```
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkacronym}{%
 \glsxtrdopostpunc{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{ab}}}}
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkgeneral}{%
 \glsxtrdopostpunc{\glsxtrifwasfirstuse{}{\textsuperscript{gl}}}}
```

This shifts the superscript after the punctuation mark.

Comment: At first glance, it looks exactly what I was looking for. I'll try it out and let you know if all problems are solved. Nevertheless, thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I Have tried it under the link https://de.overleaf.com/read/pwcdkrrpmpxk and throws the error: glslinkpresetkeys is undefined

Comment: have i missed to lod a package??

Comment: @DrDorianXD The version of `glossaries-extra` on Overleaf is too old.

Comment: @DrDorianXD Try `\glslinkpostsetkeys` instead of `\glslinkpresetkeys`.

Comment: @ NicolaTalbot now it works perfect. Ty